# TextArea not updating on data from other device

Tags: java, events, javafx, listener, fxml

I am working on my first JavaFX app with FXML file. 
My program consists of few elements:

- addDeviceButton (addMyoButton)
- few TextArea, that will have printed data collected from device.

Short description of working:

1. Pressing addDecideButton should start collecting data from
   DataController (DeviceListener),
2. Collected data and system
   communicates should be printed to TextAreas.

I have two problems:

1. printing in TextArea doesn't work,
2. app freezes (doesn't respond after pressing addMyoButton)

In 1) I have no idea what's wrong. With 2) I think I shouldn't put running dataCollector in method responsible for button event. However, I'm not sure how to make this properly.

Do you have any suggestions, ideas how I should write these fragments?? 
Is the problem in FXML or methods?

Responsible of this part of FXML file looks like:

```
<TextArea fx:id="communicateTextField" 
prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" >

<Button fx:id="addMyoButton"
onAction="#addMyo" >
```

Method addMyo(), that runs after pressing button.

```
public void addMyo(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Hub hub = new Hub("com.example.hello-myo");

        communicateTextField.setText("Attempting to find a Myo...");
        Myo myo = hub.waitForMyo(10000);

        if (myo == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find a Myo!");
            communicateTextField.setText(""Unable to find a Myo!");
        }

        communicateTextField.setText("Connected to a Myo armband!");
        DeviceListener dataCollector = new DataCollector();
        hub.addListener(dataCollector);

            while (true) {
            hub.run(1000 / 20);
            communicateTextField.setText(dataCollector);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

Method for printing communicates to TextArea
public void printCommunicate(String communicate) {
    communicateTextField.setText(communicate);
}
```

Comment: `while (true)` is preventing the JavaFX application thread from performing any painting or user input processing.  To regularly execute JavaFX code, you need a [ScheduledService](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will read about this and try use it.